# Form field within a paragraph of a pdf. It's possible?

Tags: pdf, adobe, acrobat

I have a pdf file that I want to convert into a form so I can edit it easier. I already saw how to add text fields but I would like to know if it is possible to add text fields within a paragraph, so the text is fenced adapting to how long the value of the field is and it looks better

I am using Adobe Acrobat pro, but if i need another program i can use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is only possible to visually layout the PDF document so that it appears "as if" the form field is in a paragraph. It is impossible to "insert" a form field into a paragraph so that it "moves with" the text.

The reason is that:

1. There is no concept of paragraphs in PDF files.
2. Text is drawn on the page in the page content stream, while form fields live in a completely different structure outside of the page content stream.